# Gradle to pull down dependencies into local lib dir

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependency-management

I have the following list of JAR dependencies (the following is my **entire** `build.gradle` file):

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.2.3'
    compile 'com.wordnik:swagger-annotations:1.3.4'
    compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA'

    compile 'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:0.7.0'
    compile 'io.dropwizard:dropwizard-client:0.7.0'
    compile 'com.wordnik:swagger-jaxrs_2.10:1.3.4'
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:8.1.14.v20131031'
}
```

I would like to run Gradle and have it pull all of these JARs (and their transitive deps) from  Maven and place the JARs in a local `lib` directory.

When I run this I get a `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` message, but I don't see a `lib` directory under my main `TestGradle`root` dir. I was expecting to see a directory that would contain all of these JARs as well as their transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use separate 'compile' for each library.

This is how it looks on mine android project:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexey Odinstov (+1) - but this doesn't work for me. The `MissingMethodException` is troubling to me: makes me think that Gradle isn't set up correctly or something.